# send file from formik reactjs to springboot using axios with saga

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux-saga, formik, saga

i can send file "userPicture" from postman and get it in the backend (springboot )and i save it to my database mongodb without any problem
but when i send the picture from the form i use Formik component in reactjs and axios
i display the content of my input userPicture i get 
[image]

in axios i made this to sent the request. for boundary i dont know what is i made copy past "WebKitFormBoundaryQ0pBuvRC1EzDAQWT" from an exemple

```
  try {
        const { user } = action;
        console.log(user);
        const request = yield axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: ENDPOINTS.USER + '/add',
            data: user,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryQ0pBuvRC1EzDAQWT----' }
        });
```

in the backend i get this error

> ,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile)
>   throws java.io.IOException: Required request part
>   'userPicture' is not present

i get the same error in postman when i send request without userPicture parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you sending the file incorrectly. If you want to send `multipart/form-data` from client to server, you need to use `FormData`.

**Like this**

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('usePicture', user)
```